# Emoticons of Western style or Japanese style

Tags: emotions

Today I saw a lot of native English speakers using various kaomojis, emoticons of Japanese style, on YouTube! I had never seen English-speaking people using them, so I was very surprised. Do they often use kaomojis? Which do they use more often, emoticons of Japanese style or those of Western style? Do they understand what feelings kaomojis express?

―10 examples of Western style―

```
 1. :-) 
 2. :-(
 3. :-D
 4. ;-(
 5. :-P
 6. &-|
 7. (:-<
 8. ~:-(
 9. :-Q
10. =(8-O)
```

―10 examples of Japanese style―

```
 1. (^_^)v
 2. ヾ(;ﾟ;Д;ﾟ;)ﾉﾞ
 3. ┐(´д｀)┌
 4. (๑˃̵ᴗ˂̵)/
 5. (´；ω；`)
 6. ((( ；ﾟДﾟ)))
 7. ヽ(*´∀｀)八(´∀｀*)ノ
 8. ε=ε=┏(・＿・)┛
 9. ʕ•̫͡•ʕ*̫͡*ʕ•͓͡•ʔ-̫͡-ʕ•̫͡•ʔ*̫͡*ʔ-̫͡-ʔ
10. ٩(๑•̀ω•́๑)۶
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because emoticons and kaomojis aren't part of "English". Whether Anglophones use and/or understand them the same as Japanese is a matter of culture, not language use as such.

Comment: Japanese style emoticons (horizontal) are not as common on English language sites as Western style emoticons (vertical) but I have noticed them more lately. I personally don't recognize any of the Japanese style ones you gave.

Comment: @Mitch #1 is definitely a cutesy eyes-scrunched-up half-smile, and #9 looks like a deformed teddy bear being repeatedly clobbered round the head with a blunt instrument. Not sure exactly what the progression from one to the other is.

Comment: TulipSaita I reformatted the kaomojis and emoticons because they were squashed onto single lines. If not okay please undo my edit.

Comment: Well I do not understand any of the Japanese ones. In fact I only understand 1 to 5 of the Western ones! I guess I am too old .

Comment: [My answer to a related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317617/what-is-the-difference-between-emoji-and-emoticon/430042#430042) may just be of interest to you Tulip Saita. It doesn't answer all of your questions, but it should provide you with some information on western usage.